# Download embedded PDF loaded in WKWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview

While loading `HTML5` page from url I'm getting pdf somewhere in that page and I have to download that pdf or save it as `base64`.

This is where the pdf is in the HTML code. I cannot simply hit the 'src' URL and get the pdf.

```
< embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" id="plugin" src="https://myurl.com/fileToOpen.pdf” type="application/pdf" internalinstanceid="8" title="">
```

Any JS which can help me get `base64` string of that or any other method to download?

Comment: Can you execute a javascript code inside the webview?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Yes.

Comment: Can you explain more? or provide an image of the webPage you trying to load?

Comment: @Nitesh please have a look at my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

From the [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) they say

> The Fetch API provides an interface for fetching resources (including
>   across the network). It will seem familiar to anyone who has used
>   XMLHttpRequest

You can also use the following string to get the base64 String from the WKWebview

```
 let s = "path = document.getElementById(\"plugin\").src\n" +
        "\n" +
        "fetch(path).then(function (response) {\n" +
        " response.body.getReader().read().then(function(result) {\n" +
        " return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, result.value));\n" +
        " }).then(function(b64) {\n" +
        " window.webkit.messageHandlers.myInterface.postMessage(b64);\n" +
        " });\n" +
        "});"
```

### both fetch and xmlhttp works async.. all you need to do is wait when the processing gets completed pass it to the Swift using javascript's bridge to ios (WKScriptMessageHandler)

Use the following code to **get the base64 string from javascript to Swift**. 
I am using [WKScriptMessageHandler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkscriptmessagehandler) to get the callback from Javascript **when the base64 string is ready to be consumed**. In the String s you just need to pass the url of the pdf and it will do a ajax request to get the pdf file and then convert it to base64 string.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var btnPDF: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var webViewParentView: UIView!
    var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView?
    var webView: WKWebView!
    @objc func didSelect(_ sender: UIView){
        let s="var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();\n" +
            "xhr.open(\'GET\', \"https://codingexceptions.com/wkwebview/dummy.pdf\", true);\n" +
            "\n" +
            "xhr.responseType = \'arraybuffer\';\n" +
            "\n" +
            "xhr.onload = function(e) {\n" +
            " if (this.status == 200) {\n" +
            " var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(this.response);\n" +
            " var i = uInt8Array.length;\n" +
            " var binaryString = new Array(i);\n" +
            " while (i--)\n" +
            " {\n" +
            " binaryString[i] = String.fromCharCode(uInt8Array[i]);\n" +
            " }\n" +
            " var data = binaryString.join(\'\');\n" +
            "\n" +
            " var base64 = window.btoa(data);\n" +
            "\n" +
            "window.webkit.messageHandlers.myInterface.postMessage(base64);" +
            "\n" +
            " }\n" +
            "};\n" +
            "\n" +
        "xhr.send();\n"
        webView.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "myInterface")
        webView?.evaluateJavaScript(s, completionHandler: {(string,error) in
            print(error ?? "no error")
        })
    }
    func setupWebView(){
        webView = WKWebView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: webViewParentView.frame.width, height: webViewParentView.frame.height))
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webViewParentView.addSubview(webView)
        activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
        activityIndicator?.center = self.view.center
        self.view.addSubview(activityIndicator!)
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://codingexceptions.com/wkwebview/index.php")!))
        activityIndicator?.startAnimating()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        btnPDF.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.didSelect(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
         setupWebView()
    }
}
extension ViewController: WKScriptMessageHandler{
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
         print("Message received: \(message.name) with body: \(message.body)")
    }
}
extension ViewController: WKNavigationDelegate{
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        self.activityIndicator?.stopAnimating()
        self.activityIndicator?.removeFromSuperview()
        self.activityIndicator = nil
    }
}
```

Update: To get the source from the embed tag as pointed in @Tarun's answer

just put the below **line in the starting of string variable s** and pass the url in xhr.open

```
var url = document.getElementById("plugin").src
```

Comment: @Nitesh glad this worked. Is this solves your current requirement?

Comment: Yes. Also can you please help me out more with the Tarun's solution too. Or if possible update the answer with that too.

Comment: @SahilManchanda, This was the part I didn't know since it involves iOS code. Thanks for the update :-)

Comment: @SahilManchanda Can u please help. Now all sudden above script stopped working. only thing change in the website js is internalinstanceid="4" previous it was 8.

Comment: <body style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; margin: 0px; background-color: rgb(82, 86, 89);"><embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" id="plugin" src="" type="application/pdf" internalinstanceid="4"></body>

Comment: @Nitesh hi, can you share the url that you are trying. or you can attach safari developer controls with simulator and check on console what error you are getting.

Comment: I don't know how after after adding a completionHandler it started working. Thanks for help @SahilManchanda

Comment: @SahilManchanda Can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52928183/get-page-loaded-event-on-webview

Answer (score 5):

This question asked sometimes back,
But if someone looking for **swift** solution with **WKWebView** to download .pdf or any file on File manager, this is how I ended-up

```
class WebPortalVC: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate,WKUIDelegate, UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate,URLSessionDownloadDelegate {
```

override following function, that will intercept url, in our case we check ulr ending with .pdf and .csv and redirect to open with file manger view. which enable view file, download and save on device storage, airdrop or share with other apps

just add following functions and check.

```
 func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    if let url = navigationAction.request.url {

        print("fileDownload: check ::  \(url)")

        let extention = "\(url)".suffix(4)

        if extention == ".pdf" ||  extention == ".csv"{
            print("fileDownload: redirect to download events. \(extention)")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.downloadPDF(tempUrl: "\(url)")
            }
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
            return
        }

    }

    decisionHandler(.allow)
}

func downloadPDF(tempUrl:String){
    print("fileDownload: downloadPDF")
    guard let url = URL(string: tempUrl) else { return }
    let urlSession = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue())
    let downloadTask = urlSession.downloadTask(with: url)
    downloadTask.resume()
    //showHUD(isShowBackground: true); //show progress if you need
}
func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
    print("fileDownload: documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview")
    return self
}
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
    // create destination URL with the original pdf name
    print("fileDownload: urlSession")
    guard let url = downloadTask.originalRequest?.url else { return }
    print("fileDownload: urlSession \(url)")
    let documentsPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let destinationURL = documentsPath.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
    // delete original copy
    try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: destinationURL)
    // copy from temp to Document
    do {
        try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: location, to: destinationURL)
        myViewDocumentsmethod(PdfUrl:destinationURL)
        print("fileDownload: downloadLocation", destinationURL)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            NBMaterialToast.showWithText(self.view, text: "Download Completed", duration: NBLunchDuration.long)
        }
    } catch let error {
        print("fileDownload: error \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
   // dismissHUD(isAnimated: false); //dismiss progress
}
func myViewDocumentsmethod(PdfUrl:URL){
    print("fileDownload: myViewDocumentsmethod \(PdfUrl)")
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let controladorDoc = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: PdfUrl)
        controladorDoc.delegate = self
        controladorDoc.presentPreview(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

PS: Using answer as comments, as I need formatting

You should execute the below JavaScript in the webview

```
path = document.getElementById("plugin").src

fetch(path).then(function (response) {
    response.body.getReader().read().then(function(result) {
        return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, result.value));
    }).then(function(b64) {
        window.pdf_data = b64;
    });
});
```

Then you can execute another query to access the `window.pdf_data` assuming get return value from a javascript execution is possible?

Comment: The above code didn't work Or I didnt understood it how to get it work. Just for example this is how I get base64 String for image, it it helps you guide me. var c = document.createElement('canvas'); var ctx = c.getContext('2d'); ctx.drawImage(document.getElementById('captcha_id'), 100, 40); var value = c.toDataURL(); value.split(',')[1];

Comment: How do you access value from the swift code? Sorry I am not a IOS dev

Comment: 'window.pdf_data = b64;' This b64 is string here?

Comment: Yes this, will contain the base64 string. But remember this is async code. SO the value won't be available immediately

Comment: I'm also trying this method with the answer provided by Sahil.

Answer (score -2):

Are you looking to download the PDF to your iPhone or to your Mac? Generally, it's not possible to download PDFs directly to your iPhone because the iPhone doesn't natively have the capability to store PDFs. You'd need to have iBooks or iCloud Drive and then open the PDF in another window, followed by manually downloading it. There would still need to be user-interaction before you download the PDF, meaning the user would have to approve the download. Direct download via the injection of JavaScript into a `WKWebView` instance is is not possible.

Comment: We can also store it in Documents if I’m not wrong.  About direct download, yeah even I started to think it’s not possible. Just wanted to give a try as I’m not gd with JS.

Comment: Documents, you mean on a Mac?

Comment: There is no documents app on the iPhone. You could try with the Google Drive app, but it would be the same process as using iBooks or iCloud Drive.

Comment: Its possible to download pdf directly to iPhone Files.