# Intercept WKWebView for pdf download

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, intercept, urlsession

I have weburl which I converted the in too an iOS app(by opening that url in webview).I have to download pdf from webview. I am ending up with downloading login html page as tmp file in document directory when I clicked download.

I assuming that it's not downloading the pdf because we are creating new session. I am not sure how to proceed?

tried below but now working

```
let username = "sss@gmail.com"
            let password = "test"
            let loginString = String(format: "%@:%@", username, password)
            let loginData = loginString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
            let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedString()
            var newReq = navigationAction.request
            newReq.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

            let task = DownloadManager.shared.activate().dataTask(with: navigationAction.request)
            task.resume()
```

2. tried authentication delgate but now calling

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                    task: URLSessionTask,
                    didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge,
                    completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {

        completionHandler(URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential, URLCredential(user: "sss@gmail.com", password: "test", persistence: URLCredential.Persistence.none))
        debugPrint("Challenge: \(task)")

    }
```

any idea?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

if you looking for download pdf from WKWebView, check my solution in here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60614921/1025070