# Download .pdf or .ppt by WebView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webview

I'm using the "webview" component to access the website. In an undetermined part of site, we have .pdf and .ppt format files.
Can I download these files when the user clicks on them? Today, the application only opens .pdf and .ppt, but I would like to download it.

My code is in pt_BR.

```
class PortalAcademicoViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        carregaSite()

    }


    func carregaSite(){
        /*
        let url = URL(string: "")
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
        urlRequest.cachePolicy = .returnCacheDataElseLoad
        webView.loadRequest(urlRequest) */


        //carregar o arquivo html
        let htmlFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "portalacademico", ofType: "html")
        let html = try? String(contentsOfFile: htmlFile!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookieAcceptPolicy = .always
        self.webView.frame = self.view.bounds
        webView.loadHTMLString(html!, baseURL: Bundle.main.resourceURL)

        //voltar e avançar entres as paginas do webview
        let swipeLeftRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipe(recognizer:)))
        let swipeRightRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipe(recognizer:)))

        swipeLeftRecognizer.direction = .left
        swipeRightRecognizer.direction = .right

        webView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeftRecognizer)
        webView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRightRecognizer)
        //fim

    }



    //trabalhando com avançar e voltar webview
    @objc private func handleSwipe(recognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        if (recognizer.direction == .left) {
            if webView.canGoForward {
                webView.goForward()
            }
        }

        if (recognizer.direction == .right) {
            if webView.canGoBack {
                webView.goBack()
            }
        }
    }
    //FIM

}
```

Comment: You should always write your code in English.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should perform download task with Javascript.
Check your requests in func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction ...) and if there download request found call the javascript method.

Here is someone already done pdf download with wkwebview.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/108394

Answer (score 1):

You can set a `UIWebViewDelegate` to your WebView and check for PDF and PPT files in `webViewShouldStartLoadWithRequest`. `webViewShouldStartLoadWithRequest` is called every time when the user clicks on a link.

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

    if request for a PPT or PDF file {
        downloadFile()
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebviewdelegate/1617945-webview?language=objc

Side note: You are currently using UIWebView which is deprecated. You should consider using WKWebView instead.

Answer (score 0):

with **WKWebView** download .pdf and .ppt or any specific file, check my solution in here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60614921/1025070